# int16_t to float MPU6050 accel reading overflow in arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors

I'm having some trouble to identify why sometimes I get strange values and overflow from MPU6050 sensor. 
I have an ATM328P micro reading values from a DROTEK 10 DOF IMU sensor, one of these values is the acceleration one, and it sometimes become ovf or behaves in a weird way. This is the code I'm using for it:

```
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU=0x69;
int16_t ax,ay,az;
float acc[3] = {0, 0, 0};
float S = 0.00006103515625; // scale factor g/LSB 4/65536

void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU,6,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  az=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  ay=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  ax=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)

 acc[0] = ax*S;
 acc[1] = ay*S;
 acc[2] = az*S;
}
```

Why would these last acc values from the array overflow or behave in a weird way (not expected values) sometimes, and why when it starts behaving weird it doesn't recover anymore? I've looked for problems regarding int16_t to float conversion but haven't found any clue that could help me. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064991/int16-t-to-float-conversion-weirdness) there is another similar issue, but I think it won't apply to mine cause the ax, ay and az values I get from the sensor are far away from the limits, and I'm converting to a larger format number.

Does a anyone have any idea?

I'm starting to think that it may be hardware thing.

Comment: "Arduino" is neither C nor C++.

Comment: Sorry for the C and C++ tags

Answer (score 0):

Well i run into the same problem and i figured the conversion of the accelerometer values from int16_t into a float data type was the issue. Not sure why that it